# I need a better idea as use of GetAwaiter().OnCompleted for a Grpc AsyncUnaryCall

Tags: c#, async-await, grpc

I try to read the response header/metadata from a grpc service call. In order to do this at one central point I use a custom call invoker which encapsulate the real underlying `HttpClientInvoker`.

My calling code is very simple so far, just call 3 times

```
var greeter = new GreeterClient(new MyCustomCallInvoker());
await greeter.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = nameof(TestSayHello) });
await greeter.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = nameof(TestSayHello) });
await greeter.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = nameof(TestSayHello) });
```

The custom invoker does something like this

```
public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(
                                    Method<TRequest, TResponse> method,
                                    string host,
                                    CallOptions options,
                                    TRequest request)
{
   var result = Invoker.AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(method, host, options, request);
   Action updateMetadata = delegate
   {
      var trailers = result.GetTrailers();
      UpdateMetadata(trailers);
   };
   result.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(updateMetadata);
   return result;
}
```

I know use of `GetAwaiter()` isn't very nice. Unfortunately, the invoker doesn't use `Task` here and `AsyncUnaryCall` is sealed.

However, the call to greeter passed 2 times before the trailers was updated for the first time.

I didn't see a way to update the local trailers immediately after `Invoker.AsyncUnaryCall` has passed and before its going back to the calling code without blocking the process. (EDIT: if i just put a Console.Write("done") in OnCompleted it works as expected.)

It is possible in some way?

Comment: @yogihosting  its not related to my question. this is a just seo link for ur site i guess.

Comment: I assume you mean `CallInvoker/DefaultCallInvoker` not `HttpClientInvoker`? Also, where does `OnCompleted` come from?

Comment: @IanKemp I assume it's this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.oncompleted?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @ChrisYungmann Ah, I was expecting something in gRPC... not a shipped method marked as "This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." IDisposable, you probably shouldn't be using that method considering the documentation.

Comment: @IanKemp my encapsulated call invoker comes from GrpcChannel.CreateInvoker() which is a 'HttpClientInvoker' behind the scenes. GetAwaiter seems my only option here, i.e watch for the title ;)  i need a better idea.

Comment: Sorry, you are right @IDisposable the answer I posted will not work due to the issue you mentioned. Maybe this will be of some help? https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21489 Looks like you ought to return a new `AsyncUnaryCall` instance that you can then provide any asynchronous logic.

Comment: @ChrisYungmann Post that link as an answer.

Comment: @Chris Yungmann Interceptors in grpc.net are designed as pre call interceptors. afaik there no post call interceptors available.

Answer (score 0):

Took a while but a i found a solution i want to share with the community.
The problem here was AsyncUnaryCall(which spend the TaskAwaiter)
is sealed.

I take a look in the grpc source and see AsyncUnaryCall is just a container for a of bunch callbacks. ctor prototypes looks as follows:

```
public AsyncUnaryCall(Task<TResponse> responseAsync, Task<Metadata> responseHeadersAsync, Func<Status> getStatusFunc, Func<Metadata> getTrailersFunc, Action disposeAction);

public AsyncUnaryCall(Task<TResponse> responseAsync, Func<object, Task<Metadata>> responseHeadersAsync, Func<object, Status> getStatusFunc, Func<object, Metadata> getTrailersFunc, Action<object> disposeAction, object state)
```

That was the solution for my problem, to create a second AsyncUnaryCall as a proxy wich encapsulate the origin AsyncUnaryCall and modify them slightly by adding GetTrailers in the ResponseAsync Callback.

Hope this helps someone in the future.